# ngrx update array of objects - map does not exist on state

Tags: angular, ngrx

Trying to update an array of objects via ngrx-reducer I found some examples in the web (e.g. https://blog.strongbrew.io/Redux-best-practices/)

Some of them try to perform state.map, but I get an error "property 'map' does not exist on type 'state'".

In an array of objects, I would like to update the property languageStrg of one of the objects. Here is my code:

```
export function langsReducer(state = initialState, action: LangsActions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.SETLANG: {
            return state.map(obj =>
                obj.languagePurpose === action.payload.languagePurpose ?
                {...state, languageStrg: action.payload.languageStrg} :
                obj);
            }
}
```

How could I rewrite the code so that the update works?

Comment: Could you please show the definition of `initialState`?

Comment: const initialState: State = {
    languages : [
        {languagePurpose: 'frontend', languageStrg: 'de'},
        {languagePurpose: 'backend', languageStrg: 'de'},
    ],
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it will be

```js
export function langsReducer(state = initialState, action: LangsActions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.SETLANG: {
            return {
                ...state,
                languages: state.languages.map(obj =>
                    obj.languagePurpose === action.payload.languagePurpose
                        ? {...obj, languageStrg: action.payload.languageStrg}
                        : obj
                    )
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your reducer should return the state in the default case in the switch case.

your initial state should look like this if you want to use arr of objects

```
const initialState = {
    arr = []
}
```

Comment: Yes, a default follows after this case, but isn't it possible to define values for the initial state? Maybe like this: const initialState: State = {
    languages : [
        {languagePurpose: 'frontend', languageStrg: 'de'},
        {languagePurpose: 'backend', languageStrg: 'de'},
    ],
};